# How can I arrange all the image files in an folder randomly?

Tags: image, batch-file, windows-10, directory

I am using Windows, I want to arrange image files in a specific folder randomly, instead of sorting them in an specific way, is there a way to arrange them randomly ?

Comment: Windows Explorer controls the display order. There is no way to *randomly* order them without changing the filenames. The same applies when using `dir` from a command prompt - you're restricted to a limit number of ordering options, which you can see by typing `dir /?` at a command prompt. Why do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: Thanks.
For an Android app which contains wallpaper, I downloaded according to category and I wanted them in random manner that&#39;s why.

Comment: Files in NTFS directories are stored in alphabetical order. So no sorting will give you a sorted list. As `dir` shows. FAT32 in in order added, having regard deleted entries will be reused.

Comment: You can't change the order to be random, but you can access the files randomly from another program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) will sort the files however you tell it to sort them.
You could sort the files by Name, Date, Type, Size, etc.
Sorting them randomly requires one of these filters to be randomized as well.

Now, depending on what you need the files to be randomized for can change the needed answer for your question. For example, if what you need is a way to randomize your screensaver or slideshow, this is not the correct way to phrase your question.

However, if all you need is some way to randomize the contents of a folder, here's some code HowToGeek posted a while back:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Randomly renames every file in a directory.

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM 0 = Rename the file randomly.
REM 1 = Prepend the existing file name with randomly generated string.
SET PrependOnly=0

REM 1 = Undo changes according to the translation file.
REM This will only work if the file "__Translation.txt" is in the same folder.
REM If you delete the translaction file, you will not be able to undo the changes!
SET Undo=0


REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Do not modify anything below this line unless you know what you are doing.
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET TranslationFile=__Translation.txt

IF NOT {%Undo%}=={1} (
    REM Rename files
    ECHO You are about to randomly rename every file in the following folder:
    ECHO %~dp0
    ECHO.
    ECHO A file named %TranslationFile% will be created which allows you to undo this.
    ECHO Warning: If %TranslationFile% is lost/deleted, this action cannot be undone.
    ECHO Type "OK" to continue.
    SET /P Confirm=
    IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
        ECHO.
        ECHO Aborting.
        GOTO :EOF
    )

    ECHO Original Name/Random Name > %TranslationFile%
    ECHO ------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
        IF NOT %%A==%~nx0 (
            IF NOT %%A==%TranslationFile% (
                SET Use=%%~xA
                IF {%PrependOnly%}=={1} SET Use=_%%A

                SET NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!
                ECHO %%A/!NewName!>> %TranslationFile%

                RENAME "%%A" "!NewName!"
            )
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Undo mode.
    IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
        ECHO Missing translation file: %TranslationFile%
        PAUSE
        GOTO :EOF
    )
    FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B" "%%A"
    DEL /F /Q %TranslationFile%
)
```

Comment: For those who were confused about how to use the script above, open Notepad, paste the script and save it with the name RandomNames.bat. Then copy the file RandomNames.bat to the folder with the files to be renamed randomly. More information can be obtained at this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/57661/stupid-geek-tricks-randomly-rename-every-file-in-a-directory/